# asp.net DataSource SQL syntax

Tags: c#

I am trying to take data from two tables and show them using a GridView.

I keep getting an error around 'on' when running the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT [date], [title], [description], [views], [Id] 
FROM [bookmarks] b 
JOIN [creates] c (on [b.Id] = [c.bookmarkid]) 
ORDER BY [date] DESC
```

The SQL syntax is quite different from MySQL or Oracle SQL and I do not know how to specify the aliases (I think there is the problem).

Comment: `(on [b.Id] = [c.bookmarkid])` should go `on ([b.Id] = [c.bookmarkid])`

Comment: oh, dumb me...fixed that, but still I get an error: invalid column name b.Id and c.bookmarkid

Comment: _[b].[Id] = [c].[bookmarkid]_

Comment: Could you specifically say where you are going to execute that query? is it MySQL? or Oracle? or SQLServer?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is to do with the position of your square brackets in:

```
[b.Id] = [c.bookmarkid]
```

By putting them around the alias and column name "b.id" is being parsed as a column name rather than table.columnname.

I'd try:

```
 [b].[Id] = [c].[bookmarkid]
```

or simply

```
b.Id = c.bookmarkid
```